# How to cancel a run for a non-existent runs-on member in github workflows?

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

```yaml
name: Test

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - action/test

jobs:
  super_test:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu22.04]
        arch: [X64, X86, ARM64]
    runs-on: [self-hosted, "${{ matrix.os }}", "${{ matrix.arch }}"]
    name: "With my ${{ matrix.os }}:${{ matrix.arch }}"
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.1
      - name: Print Something
        run: git branch
```

I have a self-hosted runner with the label 'ubuntu22.04,X64' There are no other runners available. In this case, I would like the jobs for the non-existent runner to be canceled. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Currently, according to the [Usage limits](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/about-self-hosted-runners#usage-limits) section on the official doc: _Each job for self-hosted runners that has been queued for at least 24 hours **will be canceled**. The actual time in queue can reach up to 48 hours before cancellation occurs. **If a self-hosted runner does not start executing the job within this limit, the job is terminated and fails to complete**._

Comment: Now, if you want to cancel the job sooner, you could eventually check the [status service](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/managing-self-hosted-runners/configuring-the-self-hosted-runner-application-as-a-service#checking-the-status-of-the-service), but that would need to be done outside of the workflow (a batch or script that would run somewhere else), and cancel the queued workflow automatically if the service is down.